# How to limit items in a list, but still show complete groups in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have the following data set:

```
update (id, update_time)
1    <a timestamp>
2    <a timestamp>

item_update (update_id, item_id)
1    327
1    328
1    496
2    345
2    477
```

What I want to do is display them as follows in a page:

```
On March 6, 2012:
327
328
496

On July 7, 2012:
345
477
```

More or less. The thing is that the data set is expected to get pretty big. I can't have all that in a single page. However, if I just limit them to an arbitrary number, then the groups get cut off in the middle. If I limit them by update, then I might get too few in one page and too many in another.

How can I limit the result set so that I get as many groups (updates) as possible without exceeding a certain amount of items?

Comment: This is usually better handled in code rather than SQL.

Comment: How so? If I did it externally I would have to individually select every update, until I counted enough items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you won't want to split a group, then you can simply

```
select update_id, count(*) cnt from item_update group by update_id;
```

This will give you counts for each update_id.  Then it's just a matter of looping through the update_ids and until your cumulative reaches (or passes) your page max and then firing another query for all those update_ids...

There may be edge cases though where one update group has 1 item and the next has 1000... there it would probably make sense to allow your pagination to break on groups...

```
page1

group1
  item1
  item2
  item3
group2
  item1
  item2

page2

group2
  item3
  item4
  etc...
```

then it's just a matter of using the limit clause with sorting...

Answer (score 1):

The following query

```
select a.id, floor(ifnull(sum(b.update_count),0) / 50) as start_page
from updte as a
left join
    (select update_id, case when count(1) > 50 then 50 else count(1) end as update_count
     from item_update group by update_id) as b
  on a.id > b.update_id
group by a.id
```

will give you the page number that each `update_id` group should start on (assuming that we want to show no more then 50 items on page except when there is more than 50 items in group). Knowing `start_page` for each `update_id` you can display only relevant `update_id` from `item_update`.

Comment: The problem with this is that if there are a million updates (which there will certainly be), I'll get a million rows which my program will have to handle. Add to that the fact that I'll have to search linearly for the updates I'll have to display, and I get a huge performance issue on the program side.

Comment: No, if you buffer results obtained this way. As far as I understand your updates come in linear fashion, so it is possible to calculate start_page as new updates come. With index on start_page you can easily obtain relevant update_ids with no performance issues.

Comment: You do not have to search linearly. You query for the exact start_page, I mean: `select id from (... the query above ...) where start_page = :my_current_page`.

Comment: That's true. Let me look at it once more then.

Comment: Okay, tested it, and it works... sort of. Here is my result set when using 12 items per page, all groups with 10 items: (1,0), (2,0), (3,1), (4,2). 3 and 4 should be on the same page. My assumption is that the leftovers from the previous page are carrying over to the next for some reason.

Comment: Yes, actually the solution is wrong. Forget it. You cannot calculate number of page for item by simple division if number of items is different on each page. The only way it could work is if you precalculated page_number in additional table every time new item arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT     b.update_time, a.item_id           
FROM       item_update a
INNER JOIN updte b ON a.update_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN  item_update c ON a.update_id = c.update_id
      AND  a.item_id <= c.item_id
GROUP BY   a.update_id, a.item_id
HAVING     COUNT(1) <= 2
```

The `2` in the `HAVING` clause is the number of items to limit per group (limited via *n* highest `item_id` per group). You can fiddle around with this solution using the demo:

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0a55/39/0)

Notice if you change the `2` to a `3`, you'll get one more result for March 6th.

---

If you want your results to be displayed hierarchically, you can do this:

```
SELECT a.val
FROM
(
    SELECT     CONCAT('- - - -> ', a.item_id) AS val,
               CONCAT(b.update_time, a.item_id) AS orderfactor
    FROM       item_update a
    INNER JOIN updte b ON a.update_id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN  item_update c ON a.update_id = c.update_id AND a.item_id <= c.item_id
    GROUP BY   a.update_id, a.item_id
    HAVING     COUNT(1) <= 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(update_time, 'On %M %e, %Y:'), 
           update_time
    FROM   updte
) a
ORDER BY a.orderfactor
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0a55/16/0)

Comment: What are the CONCATS for? I don't really get this :S

Comment: @elite5472 that's to facilitate displaying the data in sets and subsets like how the OP posted in his example. Check out the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, although it's not pretty.

Basically, I have to first find all the unique `update_id` within item_update, as follows:

```
(SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT update_id 
     FROM item_update
     WHERE update_id < :my_last_id_from_previous_page
     ORDER BY update_id DESC
     LIMIT 0, :limit
) as inner_query
GROUP BY update_id) as outer_query
```

That resulting table gives me all the groups that have to be returned, so with that the rest is a piece of cake:

```
SELECT item_id, update.id, update_time FROM outer_query
INNER JOIN item_update ON (item_update.update_id = outer_query.update_id)
INNER JOIN update ON (item_update.update_id = update.id)
```

Comment: pleasy try my answer as well, hope it's a little more pretty ;]

Comment: In the end this is what worked best for me. Including a bunch of other things like descriptions and user restrictions, it turned into a 50 line monstrosity. That said, the result set is exactly what I wanted and it doesn't perform so badly either.